# Create constants by const FOO within foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, constants

Actually I define my constants like this

```
const FILE_A = 'file_a.php';
const FILE_B = 'file_b.php';
const FILE_C = 'file_c.php';
```

Now I tried to define within a foreach loop

```
$files = array('file_a', 'file_b', 'file_c');
foreach ($files as $file) {
  const strtoupper($file) = $file . '.php';
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't define class constants like that.

Comment: Couldn't I use const() like define()? Since PHP 5.3 I can use const() in global scope without any classes.

Comment: No. The rules for syntax are different. (That will change slightly in PHP 5.6 but this still won't work even then).

Answer (score 1):

You can use function [define](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.define.php):

```
$files = array('file_a', 'file_b', 'file_c');
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $filename = strtoupper($file);
  define($filename, $file . '.php');
}

print FILE_A;  // or constant("FILE_A");
// file_a.php
```

Comment: I know that it works with define(). I thought const() would be faster then define().

Comment: why be faster? use `const` for defining class/interface constants? For "global" use `define@

Comment: const() runs in compile time and define() runs in runtime.

Comment: for you this moment is essential? how it affect on perfomance? Or you define billions of constants? I use word `const` only for defining class constants-properties.

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me

Comment: @RonnyLinsener: "const() runs in compile time" -- you answered your own question as to why `const` can't be used in a `foreach` loop.